# Why doesn't the for loop in the code below run as an infinite loop (i continuing after -1 as 1 2 3...-3 -2 -1)?

Tags: c

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
    char i = 0;
    for( i<=5 && i>=-1 ; ++i ; i>0)
        printf("%d ",i); 
    return 0;
    }
```

output is 1 2 3 ...127 -128 -127 ... -3 -2 -1.Can anyone explain how it stops after printing -1?

Comment: Your `for` loop is wonky; it should be `for ( <initialisation> ; <continuation condition> ; <increment> )`, so you have "finish when `++i` is false", so since `++(-1)` returns zero, you finish after printing "-1".

Comment: I am aware of the usual syntax of initialise, condition, increment. This question was asked as a part of competitive skills in programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 for( i<=5 && i>=-1 ; ++i ; i>0)
    printf("%d ",i);
```

Here `++i` is the `condition` part.When `i=-1` and then `++i` becomes `0` which evaluates to false and the loop breaks.

Comment: @DavidBowling The OP probably already knows that.OP is interested in knowing why the loop stops.

Comment: @DavidBowling The actual question was "Can anyone explain how it stops **after** printing -1?"  , not "how does it get to -1"

Comment: @M.M-- fair enough. But I felt that the answer to this question could have provided a little more information.

Comment: @DavidBowling, no doubt your answer scrutinizes the entire aspect superbly. I would suggest new learrners to read your answer for in-depth learning.

Comment: @Shivani-- appreciated. I do grant that this answers the posted question (and did not claim otherwise), yet I may have come down a bit hard on the answerer for not being as complete as I would like; I don't think I was harsh (and there were no DVs by me). Given your comment: ["This question was asked as a part of competitive skills in programming."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962461/why-doesnt-the-for-loop-in-the-code-below-run-as-an-infinite-loop-i-continuing/44964263#comment76903283_44962461) I _would_ submit that discussion of differing behaviors on different systems is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You have your loop a bit off; it needs to be initialization, condition, increment. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<=5 && i>=-1; ++i)
        printf("%d ",i); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In general, it's best to end the output with a newline (`putchar('\n');` after the loop).  If `i` starts at 0 and increments, it can never be less than `-1`, can it?

Comment: I am aware of the usual syntax of initialise, condition, increment. This question was asked as a part of competitive skills in programming.

Answer (score 0):

Note first that the controlling expression in the `for` loop of the posted code is: `++i`. So the loop will terminate only when `++i` evaluates to `0`. The first clause of this `for` loop, `i<=5 && i>=-1`, has no effect on the behavior of the loop.

Next, note that the behavior of this code is implementation-dependent. OP has `signed char`, but another implementation may have `unsigned char`. If instead `char` was really `unsigned char`, then the behavior would be well-defined, since overflow of `unsigned` integer types wraps around. It is likely that an `unsigned char` would have a range [0, 255], so when `i` reaches 255, `++i` evaluates to `0`, ending the loop and leaving the last printed result as `255`.

But OP is working with `signed char`, and the behavior of `signed` integer overflow is implementation-defined. It appears that OP implementation also wraps around on overflow for `signed` integer types, so with a `signed char` range of [-128, 127], when `i` reaches 127, `i++` evaluates to `-128` (wrapping around), and the loop continues until `i` reaches -1, at which point `++i` evaluates to 0. The loop is terminated and the final printed result is `-1`.

Also note that there is a type mismatch between the conversion specifier and the argument in the `printf()` statement; `%d` is for values of type `int`, and `i` is a `char`. According to the Standard, a mismatched conversion specifier and argument cause undefined behavior. Yet, here the day is saved by the integer promotions, which are applied to the arguments of variadic functions, of which `printf()` is one. `i` is promoted to type `int`, and there is no undefined behavior.